# Subclass Properties

Tags: objective-c, properties, subclass

I'd like to do the following, in an abstract way:

```
// .h
@interface SomeObject : NSObject
@property (readonly) NSArray myProperty;
@end

// .m
@interface SomeObject ()
@property (readwrite) NSMutableArray myProperty;
@end

@implementation SomeObject
@end
```

According to the section [Subclassing with Properties in the Mac Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW4) it is allowed to overwrite `readonly` properties with `readwrite`. What doesn't work is using a subclass for the property type. *I used NSMutableArray as an example, but it could be any other class/subclass combination.*

According to inheritance rules, it should be ok though. `readonly` just generates the getter which also is allowed to return a subclass object.

**How do you tackle such cases when you need a subclass type for some property for internal use?**

An ugly way would be the following, but I'd like to avoid that as it means that I cannot use the `self.` getters and setters when accessing subclass methods.

```
// .h
@interface SomeObject : NSObject
@property (readonly) NSArray myProperty;
@end

// .m
@implementation SomeObject {
    NSMutableArray _myProperty;
}
@synthesize myProperty = _myProperty;
@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** (based on your edits): Your specific case after the edit is a somewhat special and common case (if it can be both at the same time), and requires some careful consideration.

The reason this is a special is because the subclass is a mutable form of the exposed class. The caller may expect that it will not change after receiving it. But if you hand back your internal object, then it might mutate. You have several options:

- Return an immutable copy. This is often the best solution for small collections. It's certainly the simplest. But if the accessor may be called often and the collection is large, it can be prohibitively expensive.
- Make your internal property immutable. If requests for the property are much more common than changes to the property, it can be more efficient to recreate the object when it mutates (using `arrayByAddingObject:`, `subarrayWithRange:` and the like).
- Warn the caller that the object being returned may change.... uggh... I've done this in one case where I needed the performance, but it's quite dangerous.
- I've never actually done it this way, but you could also create your own copy-on-write this way: Return the mutable version directly and mark a flag that it is now "dirty." When mutation is required internally, make a mutable copy and store it in your property (letting go of the old collection). This seems a lot of complexity, but might be useful for some situations, particularly if reads and writes tend to clump separately (lots of reads followed by lots of writes).

---

*OLD ANSWER based on NSObject vs. NSString:*

I assume your goal here is to make `myProperty` be of some opaque type, rather than leaking the fact that it is an `NSString`? Perhaps so you can change your mind later on how it's actually implemented? There are a few options. The easiest is to define it of type `id`. Then internally just treat it as a string. `id` can be anything. It is usually preferred over `NSObject*`.

If you want more type-safety internally, then you can create a private property with another name of type `NSString` and return it for `myProperty` like this:

### SomeObject.h

```
@interface SomeObject : NSObject
@property (readonly) id myProperty;
@end
```

### SomeObject.m

```
@interface SomeObject ()
@property (readwrite) NSString *myInternalProperty;
@end

@implementation SomeObject
- (id)myProperty {
  return myInternalProperty;
}
@end
```

Another hiding technique you can use (if hiding is very important to you) is a subclass. For example:

### SomeObject.h

```
@class MyOpaque;
@interface SomeObject : NSObject
@property (readonly) MyOpaque *myProperty;
@end
```

### SomeObject.m

```
@interface MyOpaque : NSString
@end
@implementation MyOpaque
@end

@implementation SomeObject
@end
```

Since the caller does not have an `@interface` definition for `MyOpaque`, he can't send messages to it without a compiler warning.

Comment: For my purposes, the "private property with another name" variant would be the only interesting one. The caller should be able to send messages according to the exposed type, but not for the subtype. I updated my question to reflect that a little better.

Comment: We're using your 3rd way at the moment, as we have a big array which changes often. But back to properties, how would you use the property internally in this way? Do you think the "private property with another name" would be the best shot here?

Comment: BTW while mutable classes being subclasses of nonmutables has proven to be very practical, it stumped me. It's actually not following inheritance rules. The subclass would have to follow the same invariants as its parent class, which would be that its objects don't change. But in the iOS world, often a mutable version is returned where a nonmutable is expected. Problems arise when the returning object alters the mutable object after returning like you described.

Answer (score -7):

> How do you tackle such cases when you need a subclass type for some
>   property for internal use?

Properties are explicitly not for *internal use*, they are members of a public interface.

If you need an internal value define a member field and override the setter of the property to set your internal value.

Comment: What do you mean by "properties are explicitly not for internal use?" Properties are often for internal use. It is very common to place them in private class extensions. They are only public if put in the public interface. That isn't required.

Comment: Properties are by their nature created and exist for external consumers.  If no one outside of your class had a need to access or mutate the value it shouldn't be a property, because you would use an internal field for that. They are by definition: Public Interface

Comment: It is very common (and highly recommended by many of us, including Apple) to use private properties for this. You shouldn't directly access your ivars except in init, dealloc, and inside of custom accessors.

Comment: Thats a pretty theoretical argument, using properties for private values is just plain stupid.  But none of this answers dudes question except, hey you cant do that. So if you have an awesome subclass property overriding strategy which changes the types of the superclass beyond what I recommended have at it!  Its still semantically wrong.

Comment: An objective C refresher, all member fields are private or protected to subclasses, which is enough. Properties, those cool things were invented so we didnt have to write accessors and mutators to expose those fields.  Without that need, we would have no need for properties.  Apple has KVC and they can recommend what they want, its not germane to the question at hand. If you think props are for private stuff rock on.

Comment: Too many youtube newb videos: everybody is property addicted.  Or maybe its an ARC thing. who cares

Comment: Someone please show me an an example of a @private property, that I cannot access from outside the instance.  Please seriously, if your gonna vote public interface down show me a way to create a private property, bs

Comment: @stackmonster: The idea that you wouldn't want accessors for private state is just weird. Accessors handle more than just setting a variable — they also ensure consistent memory management and enable KVO, and generally just improve the modularity of your code. I used accessors for private state long before declared properties were introduced, and I know a lot of others did too. The only logical reason to use raw ivar access outside of con/destructors and accessors is if you've profiled and found the accessors are slowing you down too much — otherwise accessors are pure win.

Comment: I use private `@properties` all the time too. And I never ever use ivars anymore (since a long time now). And Apple does and recommand this too. And it is way better, as it enforces good memory mgmt by calling the setters (even internally). `@properties` have never been reduced to be used into the public interface. **See https://gist.github.com/3739465 for a simple example**. PS : Personally I even put my `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` in the .m file to avoid them being exposed in my public API.

Comment: And expose your state to the rest of the world for no reason, and incur a performance hit for setting or getting them for no reason.  Properties are a convenience for external classes to use dot notation are forbidden from creating side affects and have no purpose for private member fields.  Show me the properties on apple foundation classes that are for "internal use"

Comment: @stackmonster: Your state isn't really any more exposed with properties than it is any other way. Yes, you can access them outside the class if you go out of your way, but the same is true of instance variables. If you don't put the property in a public header, it's as private as just about anything else in your program.

Comment: @stackmonster : just ask the Apple developers the next time you go in WWDC (that's where I had the info the first time). Declaring private properties in the .m (as in my example on gist above) makes them NOT exposed to the rest of the world. With nowadays compilers, the performance hit for this is pointless (depending on the situation, the compiler may even inline it), and the advantages (including the memory mgmt and the thread-safety) are much more interesting.

Comment: And finally, we can't show you any of this usage in Apple foundation classes because… by definition, private properties are in .m files (and we only have header files in the header) and are thus hidden and not exposed (that's precisely the point!!).

Comment: OK so what Ive learned is - obj C fields are NOT private if they are declared in the header. (not correct) And that properties defined in the .m file cant be accessed just because they are not in the header. (not correct).  Thanks guys.

Comment: Also explain how the obj c compiler is going to inline a call to objc_msgSend - yeah right.

Comment: @stackmonster: Can you define what you mean by "private" and "can't be accessed" such that ivars declared as private are meaningfully different from properties that aren't publicly declared?

Comment: ohh i thought we were all learn-ed here about what encapsulation meant, versus exposing state for convenience or hiding through obfuscation.

Comment: Look Im done with this: fact is properties would exist except to expose state.  Now if a convention now finds it convenient for ARC or KVC, so what?  You can hide stuff in a .m file great.  I dont care.  ARC is not my problem, and KVC only matter if I use it.  Properties are explicity for public use, if you find another reason for them in your use of obj C spurred on by Apple overriding this convention in whatever way, again I simply dont care.  It doesnt change the reason they exist which is to expose public interface.  To KVC or ARC or whoever.  Done talking about it, write your privt props

Comment: The fact is that properties wouldn't exist except to expose state publicly, and it doesn't matter if *the people who invented them disagree with you*? You have an interesting way of looking at the world. Apparently you know why they made properties better than they do.

Comment: Properties inside a class extension are not exposed, since they are not visible outside the .m file. You might find someone who agrees with you on your point, and you would both be wrong. Apple engineers, google engineers, and every single developer worth something know this.